# Dynamic Field Property Names Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new to this language, but have a good grasp of others.

I'm wondering how to dynamically access a field name property in objective c.

Something like:

```
self.bottomText.text = @"foo";
```

Going to:

```
NSString *bottomText = @"bottomText";

self[bottomText].text = @"foo";
```

I can understand how it would be possible to set the property like this (as per the duplication mark below):

```
[self setValue:value forKey:@"propertyName"];
```

But it seems to me that either it would have to be along the lines of:

```
[self.bottomText setValue:@"foo" forKey:@"text"];
```

Which doesn't really solve the problem, or something like:

```
[self setValue:bottomText forKey:property].text = @"foo";
```

Not knowing what property is.

Or maybe:

```
[self valueForKey:bottomText].text = @"Test";
```

But no love.

Super-confused on this one.

Comment: @Drew I disagree. Using comments to post things one has tried, ideas that haven't worked, or any information directly related to the question should be *discouraged*. If I saw something like that in a comment, I'd probably post a comment saying it should be added to the question. In any case, I'm voting to reopen. It's related to the linked post but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: fair enough. Just mark it as *Edit: * for post-closed attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty unsure, whether I did understand your Q correct. But simle KVC should solve your problem:

```
NSString *bottomText = @"bottomText";
[self valueForKey:bottomText].text = @"foo";
```

*or*

```
NSString *property = @"bottomText.text";
[self setValue:@"foo" forKeyPath:property];
```

Additionally the class of `self` could implement [keyed subscription](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#dictionary-style-subscripting).

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming `bottomText` is a `UILabel` (since it has a `text` property...), you could do something like this:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"bottomText");
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self performSelector:selector];
label.text = @"Test";
```

or if you really want it in one line:

```
[(UILabel *)[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"bottomText")] setText:@"Test"];
```